# No autocomplete and f3 not working

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

My Flashbuilder 4.6 it not working. The f3 button is not working and neither does autocomplete. Has anyone else had this problem? Know how to fix it?

I'm checking to make sure that my keyboard is not broken.

Comment: Have you restarted?  Have you restarted with the 'clean' attribute?  Which OS are you using?  Was that a joke about having a broken keyboard? Are you sure you're in the proper Eclipse Perspective?  Are your files open in a different editor somehow (such as using "open as text")?

Comment: I was not joking about the keyboard. I will try restarting with the clean attribute. I am using Windows 7.

Comment: I tried starting with -clean. No luck.

Comment: Any word on my other three questions?

Comment: I've restarted, closed all files, I'm in the Flash Builder perspective. I've just noticed that my outline window shows nothing.

Comment: Also, when I try to create a new action script class, FlashBuilder demands that I create a new project. I think that FlashBuilder no longer sees my projects as projects somehow... Let me know if tat didn't make sense.

Comment: I think the problem is that my projects are being imported as regular projects and not flash builder projects.

Comment: Your projects could have somehow lost the "Flash Builder" nature.  In Windows, you can right click on the project and there should be an option to "Add/Change Project Type".  Are any of the options clickable; or are they all greyed out? You probably need "Add Flex Project Type."  If all options are greyed out; then try to create a new project from scratch.

Comment: Great; I posted that as a formal answer then.  Feel free to accept and/or upvote at your own discretion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our comments; it sounds like your projects have somehow lost the "Flash Builder" nature.

In Windows, you can right click on the project and there should be an option to "Add/Change Project Type". You probably need to select "Add Flex Project Type" from the list of project types.

If that doesn't work, you may need to create a new project from scratch.